# Improvement list the odd numbers code in C language

Tags: c

```
void main() {
int low, high, odds = 0;
do {
    printf("Please enter a number:");
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &low);
} while (low <= 0);
do {
    printf("Please enter the second number:");
    rewind(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &high);
} while (high < 2 * low);
printf("The odd numbers between %d and %d are: ", low, high);
for (odds = low;odds <= high;odds++) {
    if (odds % 2 != 0)
    {
        printf(" %d", odds);
    }
}
printf(".\n");
system("pause");  }
```

I enter the input which '1' for 'low' variable while '10' for 'high' variable then it shows the result: "The odd numbers between 1 and 10 are 1 3 5 7 9. ".So, how can I improve or change my code by printing output:"The odd ..... 1,3,5,7,9."?

Comment: Your description is not very clear. Can you please clearly and explicitly state the exact expected behaviour? What is the important difference between what your code is showing and what you want it to show? Is it the commas? Giving an example is good but you still need to describe what the general issue is.

Comment: FYI `rewind(stdin)` is practically useless on a terminal. I would avoid using it.

Comment: I assume you're asking how to add commas? Print the comma before each item except the first one.

Comment: Use `int main(int argc, char **argv)` and take the parameters from the command line.  `int low = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1; int high = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) : 10; ...`. Using `scanf` makes any program immeasurably worse.

Answer (score 1):

To add commas

```
 int first = 1;
 for (odds = low;odds <= high;odds++) {
   if (odds % 2 != 0)
   {
     if(first){ // to prevent comma before first number
        first = 0;
     }  else {
         printf("%s",",");
     }
     printf(" %d", odds);
   }
 }
```

could have been

```
 printf("%c", ',');
```

. Ie a single character, but I used %s just in case you want to add more padding

Answer (score 0):

One nice thing about odd numbers is that you know exactly where they are.  Rather that iterating over all the values and checking if each is odd, just find the first odd value and increment by 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int low = argc > 1 ? strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10) : 1;
    int high = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) : 10;
    printf("The odd numbers between %d and %d are: ", low, high);
    if( low % 2 == 0 ){
        low += 1;
    }
    for( int odd = low; odd <= high; odd += 2 ){
        printf("%s%d", odd == low ? "" : ", ", odd);
    }
    putchar('.');
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```